# Intercepting Fetch function - Request Headers

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am intercepting already intercepted fetch and I cannot read final request data (specifically request headers).

By intercepting I mean wrapping original window.fetch()

See comments below.

```
// this was already wrapped before me...
// so it's NOT pure window.fetch
const originalFetch = window.fetch;
 
window.fetch = function() {
    
    // this will be added to the request
    arguments[1].headers.append("X-Security-A", 1);
    
    // After apply() below, the arguments are changed using
    // other external functions, which also intercept the fetch
    // and they will add additional headers;
    // I don't have access to these functions.
    
    // I cannot change the resource URL, because the external
    // functions check it.
    
    // I need to read the new headers, but the [arguments]
    // remain unchanged. They are changed somewhere within this apply()
    var promise = originalFetch.apply(this, arguments);
    
    // this will be added, but will NOT be added to actual
    // request, which already happened
    arguments[1].headers.append("X-Security-B", 1);
    
    promise.then((response) => {
        
            // Here I will get the results, but the request headers
            // are still NOT here;
            // only the ones I added
            // If I look in Chrome Console the sent request
            // contains all the headers I need to see.
            
            // HOW CAN I GET THE REQUEST HEADERS HERE?

            console.log('XXX Promise', promise);
            console.log('XXX Headers ', Array.from(arguments[1].headers.entries()));
            console.log('XXX Response', response);
            return response;
        });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: arguments is a reserved keyword that indicates the params passed to a function. arguments inside the first function is not the same of arguments in the callback of `then`.

Comment: @CesarePolonara Hmm... but [arguments] inside then() are still not containing the added headers.

Comment: @CesarePolonara I think they are somewhere in the "Promise" or "Response" object, but not sure how to get it

Comment: request headers are not the same of response headers, plus you are doing arguments[1] while you have only one arg, not sure that makes any sense, but I should try it. I think you should just send the headers you need back in the response.

Comment: @CesarePolonara Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to solve... once the Fetch is wrapped... I cannot get to the final caller arguments... my current solution is to reset the Fetch and make my wrapper first, and then include the rest of the scripts

Comment: If you just want to have access to the original arguments, just save them in an an upper scope variable, like `const requestHeaders = arguments[1].headers.entries` and then you can access them inside the promise. If you worry about them being modified later on, just make a copy of the object at the begin: `const originalArgs= {...arguments[1]}` and then you can retrieve them safely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244170/discussion-between-martin-zvarik-and-cesare-polonara).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so once the window.Fetch is wrapped second time, then you cannot get the latest arguments before the actual request.

It would be perfect to be able to make the first wrap, but my script runs as last.

**However it is possible to intercept the prototype.call() and prototype.apply() and that worked for me :)**

```
const originalFetch = window.fetch;
const originalCall = window.Function.prototype.call;

window.fetch = function() {
    
    var lastCall;
    window.Function.prototype.call = function(){
        lastCall = arguments;
        return originalCall.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    
    var x = originalFetch.apply(this, arguments);

    window.Function.prototype.call = originalCall; // reset
    
    x.then((response) => {
        
        console.log("XXX intercepted:", lastCall, response);
        
        return response;
    });
    
    return x;
};
```